# Parsing Wikipedia countries, regions, cities

Tags: parsing, mediawiki, wikipedia, wikipedia-api, mediawiki-api

Is it possible to get a list of all Wikipedia countries, regions and cities with relations between them? I couldn't find any API appropriate for this task.
What is be the easiest way to parse all the information I need?
PS: I know, that there are another datasources I can get this information from. But I am interested in Wikipedia...

Comment: You should have a look at http://dbpedia.org. Parsing Wikipedia is anything but trivial.

Comment: This is a good task for either WikiData or DBPedia. Parsing infoboxes or categories would be a terribly complicated way to reinvent the wheel.

Answer (score 6):

[2020 update] this is now best done using the Wikidata Query Service, you can run super specific queries with a bit of [SPARQL](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/), example: [Find all countries and their label](https://query.wikidata.org/#SELECT%20%3Fcountry%20%3FcountryLabel%20%7B%0A%20%20%3Fcountry%20wdt%3AP31%2Fwdt%3AP279%20wd%3AQ6256%20.%0A%20%20SERVICE%20wikibase%3Alabel%20%7B%20bd%3AserviceParam%20wikibase%3Alanguage%20%22%5BAUTO_LANGUAGE%5D%2Cen%22.%20%7D%0A%7D%0A). See [Wikidata Query Help](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Wikidata:SPARQL_query_service/Wikidata_Query_Help)

---

It might be a bit tedious to get the whole graph but you can get most of the data from the experimental/non-official [Wikidata Query API](http://wdq.wmflabs.org/api_documentation.html).

I suggest the following workflow:

- Go to an instance of the kind of entities you want to work with, say [Estonia (Q191)](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q191) and look for its *instance of* (P31) properties, you will find: country, sovereign state, member of the UN, member of the EU, etc.
- Use the Wikidata Query API **claim** command to output every entity
  that as the chosen P31 property. Lets try with [country (Q6256)](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q6256):

  `http://wdq.wmflabs.org/api?q=claim[31:6256]`

It outputs an array of numeric ids: that's your countries! (notice that the result is still incomplete as there are only 141 items found: either countries are missing from Wikidata, or, as suggested by Nemo in comments, some countries are to be found in [country (Q6256) subclasses(P279)](http://wdq.wmflabs.org/api?q=claim[279:6256]))

- You may want more than ids though, so you can ask [Wikidata Official API](https://www.wikidata.org/w/api.php) for entities data:

  `https://www.wikidata.org/w/api.php?action=wbgetentities&ids=Q16&format=json&props=labels|claims&languages=en|fr`

  (here Canada(Q16) data, in json, with only claims and labels data, in English and French. Look at the [documentation](https://www.wikidata.org/w/api.php) to adapt parameters to your needs)

You can query multiple entities at a time, with a limit of 50, as follow:

```
https://www.wikidata.org/w/api.php?action=wbgetentities&ids=Q16|Q17|Q20|Q27|Q28|Q29|Q30|Q31|Q32|Q33|Q34|Q35|Q36|Q37|Q38|Q39|Q40|Q41|Q43|Q45|Q77|Q79|Q96|Q114&format=json&props=labels|claims&languages=en|fr
```

- From every countries data, you could look for entities registered as *administrative subdivisions* (P150) and repeat on those new entities.
- Aternatively, you can get all the tree of administrative subdivisions with the **tree** command. For instance, for France(Q142) that would be `http://wdq.wmflabs.org/api?q=tree[142][150]` Tadaaa, 36994 items! But that's way harder to refine given the different kinds of subdivision you can encounter from a country to another. And avoid doing this kind of query from a browser, it might crash.
- You now *just* have to find cities by countries by refining this last query with the **claim** command, and the appropriate *sub-class*(P279) of *municipality*(Q15284) entity ([all available here](http://wdq.wmflabs.org/api?q=claim[279:15284])): for France, that's *commune* (Q484170), so your request looks like

  `http://wdq.wmflabs.org/api?q=tree[142][150] AND claim[31:484170]`

  then repeat for all the countries: have fun!

Comment: Finally I read a well-researched answer on Wikidata. :) On «the data is still incomplete as there are only 141 items found»: I wouldn't say so, because you didn't consider [subclasses](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Property:P279) i.e. more specific terms than "country" which entities are using.

Comment: indeed! amending my statement

Answer (score 2):

You should go with [Wikidata](http://www.wikidata.org/) and/or [dbpedia](http://www.dbpedia.org).

Personally I'd start with Wikidata as it's directly using MediaWiki, with the same API so you can use similar code. I would use [pywikibot](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Pywikibot) to get started. Like that you can still request pages from Wikipedia where that makes sense (e.g. list pages or categories).

Here's a nice overview of [ways to access Wikidata](http://notconfusing.com/3-ways-to-access-wikidata-data-until-it-can-be-done-properly/)